Apostrophe Usage
When writing about the sound volume of my laptop, is it necessary to say "my laptop's volume"? Or can I just say "my laptop volume" (without apostrophe)?

You're not asking about the use of apostrophes, but about the possessive ('s).

Important: Note that you can't say "my laptops volume" with no apostrophe; then you have a plural. (And if you actually own several laptops and want to talk about their volume, that's "my laptops' volume.") Also don't make the common mistake of using an apostrophe when you mean a plural, like "I own several laptop's." Most style guides say not to do this even for abbreviations like "CDs."

You can, and it essentially means the same thing, but it says it differently.

"My laptop's volume" uses a possessive noun. This ascribes ownership or a direct connection. You're saying it is the volume of your laptop.
"My laptop volume" uses a noun adjunct. This is where you use one noun to describe another noun, rather like you would use an adjective. You're using the word 'laptop' to specify exactly which volume you are referring to.

In some contexts, the choice could really make a difference. For example, if you said "my dog's collar" that would mean the collar belonging to your dog, but if you said "my dog collar" it sounds like the collar belongs to you. It doesn't even imply you have a dog. In your example though, they both communicate the same thing because logically you can't have a 'laptop volume' without having a laptop.

Some pedants (or foolish people) allege that you can't use a possessive apostrophe about anything not 'belonging' to a human being, (or sometimes just 'inanimate objects') so no to the car's engine, the dog's collar, the sun's rays, etc. I think such a restriction is nonsense, and violently disagree with the San José State University Writing Center (among others) when their Kamryn Clarke says that 'Inanimate objects cannot be possessive.'

@MichaelHarvey The bee's knees.

The cat's pyjamas (or 'pajamas' for some people).

@MichaelHarvey, that restriction's proponents undoubtedly violate it all the time themselves.

...and they should all take a Long Day's pedestrian Journey westward from Land's End.
